# ansible: run command if file does not exist or if source is newer

Tags: postfix, ansible

I have the following requirement in pseudo-Makefile:

```
/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db: /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
  postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

In other words, I want to run `postmap <...>` iff `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db` does not exist or `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` was changed in this run.

I came up with the following task:

```yaml
- name: /etc/potfix/sasl_passwd
  become: yes
  template:
    src: templates/sasl_passwd.j2
    dest: /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
    mode: 0600
  register: sasl_passwd
- name: /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db exists?
  shell: test -f /etc/postfix/sasl_passdb.db
  failed_when: False
  register: sasl_passwd_exists
- name: postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
  become: yes
  shell: postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
  args:
    creates: /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
  when: sasl_passwd.changed or sasl_passwd_exists.rc != 0
```

1. It seems like a hack.
2. It always says that the "/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db exists?` step has changed (i.e. yellow in the prompt).

`when` doesn't cut it, because it will ignore the `sasl_passwd` precondition. I.e. it will never run once any kind of `sasl_passwd.db` is on disk.

How can I make the `postup` command run after any change to `sasl_passwd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *"It always says that the "/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db exists?` step has changed (i.e. yellow in the prompt)."*

```yaml
- name: /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db exists?
  shell: test -f /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
  failed_when: False
  register: sasl_passwd_exists
```

A: Module *`shell`* without attribute *`creates`* is not idempotent. Use module [*stat*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html#stat-retrieve-file-or-file-system-status) instead

```yaml
- name: /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db exists?
  stat:
    path: /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
  register: sasl_passwd_exists
```

See the result *"sasl_passwd_exists"*. Use this condition

```yaml
  when: not sasl_passwd_exists.stat.exists
```

---

> Q: *"it will never run once any kind of sasl_passwd.db is on disk"*

```yaml
- name: postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
  become: yes
  shell: postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
  args:
    creates: /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
  when: sasl_passwd.changed or sasl_passwd_exists.rc != 0
```

A: Remove the attribute *`creates`*. The task will not run when the file */etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db* exists. This is not what you want. You want to run the command when *"sasl_passwd.changed"* (or when does not exist).

```yaml
- name: postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
  become: yes
  shell: postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
  when: sasl_passwd.changed or
        (not sasl_passwd_exists.stat.exists)
```

---

Notes

- Use [*command*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#command-execute-commands-on-targets) module instead of *shell* when possible. Quoting from [*Notes*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#notes)

> *If you want to run a command through the shell (say you are using <, >, |, etc), you actually want the shell module instead. Parsing shell metacharacters can lead to unexpected commands being executed if quoting is not done correctly so it is more secure to **use the command module when possible**.*

- Use [*handlers*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change). This is Ansible way of *"Running Operations On Change"*. For example

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: Notify handler when db does not exist.
    stat:
      path: /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
    register: sasl_passwd_exists
    changed_when: not sasl_passwd_exists.stat.exists
    notify: run postmap
  - name: Create sasl_passwd and notify the handler when changed.
    become: yes
    template:
      src: templates/sasl_passwd.j2
      dest: /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
      mode: 0600
    notify: run postmap

handlers:
  - name: run postmap
    become: true
    command: postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

---

- Note that the handler will run only once. Quoting [*Handlers*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_handlers.html):

> *These ‘notify’ actions are triggered at the end of each block of tasks in a play, and will only be triggered once even if notified by multiple different tasks.*

Comment: `ansible-lint` flags that handler with “no-changed-when: Commands should not change things if nothing needs doing.”

Comment: Which is obviously a non-sense. The handler was notified because something needs to be done

Comment: Thanks, I’ve [asked for a clarification](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/discussions/3232).